# Где папка rule в Yii2

Tags: yii2, api

Только начал изучать этот фреймворк. До этого усиленно занимался ларавелем.
Вроде многое похоже на него - MVC, миграции.

Вопрос 1. Где у него что то похожее на route - чтобы задать пути?

Вопрос 2. В инструкции по развертыванию API есть такой код (похоже это и есть что то похожее на route):

```
'urlManager' => [
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
'enableStrictParsing' => true,
'showScriptName' => false,
'rules' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
],
```

где находится yii\rest\UrlRule? Такую папку не нашел. Его надо как то самостоятельно создать?

Вопрос 3. В ларавеле RESTfull API (CRUD) очень просто делается, здесь тоже просто? Если есть хороший мануал по созданию - поделитесь пожалуйста

Comment: `yii\rest\UrlRule` это неймспейс а файл может быть где угодно в проекте :),  но в данном случае если говорить про `yii` то он находится `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rest/UrlRule.php`

Comment: Быстрый rest https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/rest-quick-start